# php.ini error_reporting option messes with phpcs plugin for vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpcs

I have a vscode plugin that uses phpcs for linting.

I get this error:

```
phpcs: Unknown error ocurred. Please verify that C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs --report=json -q --encoding=UTF-8 --standard=dev/setup/codesniffer/ruleset.xml --error-severity=5 --warning-severity=5 --stdin-path=C:\xampp7\htdocs\person.class.php - returns a valid json object.
```

If I run the command on the terminal with `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` I get this output:

```bash
{"totals":{"errors":0,"warnings":0,"fixable":0},"files":{"C:\\xampp7\\htdocs\\person.class.php":{"errors":0,"warnings":0,"messages":[]}}}
```

If I run the command on the terminal with `error_reporting = E_ALL` I get this output:

```bash
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.trace_output_dir' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.trace_output_dir (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
{"totals":{"errors":0,"warnings":0,"fixable":0},"files":{"C:\\xampp7\\htdocs\\person.class.php":{"errors":0,"warnings":0,"messages":[]}}}
```

I know I can just fix `xdebug.trace_output_dir` but something else will pop up in the future.

How can I fix this? Isn't `display_errors = Off` to avoid this kind of stuff?

### Edit:

I can point the plugin to the executable `phpcs.bat`

```
@echo off
REM PHP_CodeSniffer detects violations of a defined coding standard.
REM 
REM @author    Greg Sherwood <gsherwood@squiz.net>
REM @copyright 2006-2015 Squiz Pty Ltd (ABN 77 084 670 600)
REM @license   https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/licence.txt BSD Licence

if "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%" neq "" (
    set PHPBIN=%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%
) else set PHPBIN=php

"%PHPBIN%" -d display_errors=off "%~dp0\phpcs" %*
```

Here I can set options like `-d display_errors=off` which I already have on `php.ini`

Here's the relevant options:

```ini
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
```

This shows the Xdebug error.

```ini
error_reporting = E_ALL
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
```

This does not.

Could it be that xdebug is printing to STDOUT instead of STDERR?

### Edit2:

For now I'll make do with this `php -d error_reporting=22527 -r "echo E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT;"`

### Edit3:

Errors again.

`php -i | grep "error"`

```
display_errors => STDERR => STDERR
display_startup_errors => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => C:/xampp7\php\logs\php_error_log => C:/xampp7\php\logs\php_error_log
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
track_errors => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
```

`php -d error_reporting=22527 -d display_errors=off -i | grep "error"`

```
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => C:/xampp7\php\logs\php_error_log => C:/xampp7\php\logs\php_error_log
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
track_errors => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
```

However if I do this:
`php -d error_reporting=22527 -d display_errors=off "C:\Users\david\Documents\PHP_CodeSniffer\bin\\phpcs" --version`

I get errors:

```
PHP PHP_CodeSniffer\Exceptions\DeepExitException:  PHP_CodeSniffer version 3.7.2 (stable) by Squiz (http://www.squiz.net)
 in C:\Users\david\Documents\PHP_CodeSniffer\src\Config.php on line 713
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\Users\david\Documents\PHP_CodeSniffer\bin\phpcs:0
PHP   2. PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner->runPHPCS() C:\Users\david\Documents\PHP_CodeSniffer\bin\phpcs:18
PHP   3. PHP_CodeSniffer\Config->__construct($cliArgs = *uninitialized*, $dieOnUnknownArg = *uninitialized*) C:\Users\david\Documents\PHP_CodeSniffer\src\Runner.php:67
PHP   4. PHP_CodeSniffer\Config->setCommandLineValues($args = [0 => '--version']) C:\Users\david\Documents\PHP_CodeSniffer\src\Config.php:342
PHP   5. PHP_CodeSniffer\Config->processLongArgument($arg = 'version', $pos = 0) C:\Users\david\Documents\PHP_CodeSniffer\src\Config.php:441
PHP_CodeSniffer version 3.7.2 (stable) by Squiz (http://www.squiz.net)
```

Comment: Can you name the VSCode Plugin? There might be a way to over-ride the setting when it runs the command, e.g. by using `php -d display_errors=off` in the CLI command.

Comment: @IMSoP https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs

Comment: @IMSoP I can point the executable to a `phpcs.bat` file and set `-d display_errors=off` there, but I still get the errors. Also I already have display_errors = Off on `php.ini`, I'll update my post.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's already covered in the question: "I know I can just fix xdebug.trace_output_dir but something else will pop up in the future." The question is about how to stop _messages in general_ from breaking the plugin, not _this specific deprecation message_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was solved with `-d error_reporting=22527 -d display_errors=off`

The second problem was solved with `-d xdebug.show_exception_trace=0`